# How to animate image horizontally on vertical page scroll

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm using JS to move images horizontally between page sections when the user scrolls down. My approach is to set their `margin-left` equal to `window.scrollY`. However, [as you can see in my 
CodePen link](https://codepen.io/gunderodd/pen/eYmjGOV), this means that the second image, when activated, catches up to the horizontal position of the first image. I want each slider image to be independent, so that each one would flow off the right side of the page at a different pace relative to their order on the page. Can anyone give me a tip on how to think through this problem?

```js
// this snippet controls how often the function runs, so that it doesn't run an insane amount of times
function debounce(func, wait = 2, immediate = true) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}

const sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".sliders");

function checkSlide(e) {
  sliders.forEach(slider => {

    // my console logs
    // console.log(window.innerHeight)

    // halfway through the image, start
    const slideInAt =
      window.scrollY + window.innerHeight - slider.height / 1

    // bottom of the image, 
    const imageBottom = slider.offsetTop + slider.height;

    // 
    const isHalfShown = slideInAt > slider.offsetTop;

    const isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < imageBottom;

    if (isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast) {
      // sliderImage.classList.add("active");
      slider.style.marginLeft = (window.scrollY) + "px"
    } else {
      // sliderImage.classList.remove("active");
      slider.style.marginLeft = "0px"
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", debounce(checkSlide))
```

```css
.frame {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 500px;
  /*height: 200vh;*/
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.scrollImage {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 5px;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga ad tempora in aspernatur
    pariaturlores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni,
    ut, dignissimos.</p>
  <p>Adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum..</p>
  <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga ad tempora in aspernatur
    pariaturlores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>

  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/sail-boat_318-1522.jpg" class="scrollImage sliders" />

  <p>Lorem ipsum cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni,
    ut, dignissimos.</p>
  <p>Adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum..</p>

  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/sail-boat_318-1522.jpg" class="scrollImage sliders" />

</div>
```

Comment: Check out the [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property.

Comment: I could use transforms instead of the `margin-left` method, but if they are set to equal `window.scrollY` will that effect the root of my problem?

Comment: No that will not affect the root of your problem. The root is detecting whenever an image has entered the viewport and moving it correctly based on its position on the page. I can modify your snippet with the usage of the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) which is designed to detect if an element is in the viewport. Or you can give it a try yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will read over it and see if I can think of a way to apply it to my issue.